# How to make an array within a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

```
for i in range(len(DH4_3)):
    Keqs=np.exp(-(DH4_3[i]-T4[i+127]*DS4)/(R*T4[i+127]))
    print(Keqs)
```

I want to assign the index `[i]` to each `Keqs[i]`

The goal is to be able to indexing Keq, for instance, to be able to call the different data as `Keqs[0]`, `Keqs[1]`, and so on

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Keqs = []
for i in range(len(DH4_3)):
  Keqs[i]=np.exp(-(DH4_3[i]-T4[i+127]*DS4)/(R*T4[i+127]))
print(Keqs) # print out array after all items are added
```